# Android Genymotion audio slow

Tags: android, audio, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

The audio is slow and distorted in everything (apps, videos in browser) in the latest Genymotion (2.9.0).  I tried all versions of Android.  Anyone else experiencing this?  Any solutions?  TIA.

Comment: Do you have more details?  Please share something more than "slow" or "distorted".

Comment: I shouldn't have said distorted.  The audio is slowed down.  For example, in a Youtube video, the person is speaking slower and the voice is deeper.

Comment: What's the file format you are using (codec and format)? Was it working correctly on 2.8.1?

Comment: Windows DirectSound and ICH AC97.  Everything was fine in 2.8.1.  I think it was the Windows 10 Creator update that broke it.  I tried going back to 2.8.1, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: To answer my own question, it works but you have to keep restarting the emulator til it does.  Annoying, since it used to work all the time before.